# Create number of variables based on number of columns in Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have 4 values in a column of Spark dataframe -

```
colA
Read
Join
Sort
Write
```

Output is to create 4 python variable based on the column values like -

```
v1=Read
v2=Join
v3=Sort
v4=Write
```

If there are 3 values in the column output required is to create 3 variables.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just collect them into a tuple? Doesn't make sense to have *dynamic* variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the data in the dictionary and use dictionary values as variables wherever required

```py
vars = {i:v.colA for i,v in enumerate(df.collect())}
```

Now to access the data just use dictionary with key like

```py
print(vars[0])
[Out] : Read
```